# Can Camel Kafka Connector's Salesforce connector keep the replayid?

Tags: salesforce, camel-kafka-connector

I'd like for the client to be able to subscribe and request the most recent unretrieved event. This requires tracking the replayid. I believe that this could be stored in Kafka and other connectors use Kafka for state storage like this.

Is there a way to do this with the Salesforce connector?